# What are a customer’s rights and liabilities against his bank, after it opens an account for his wife’s imposter without requiring identification?

Tags: england-and-wales, banking

A bank opened an account for a guy, and approved a credit and debit card. Because this bank has known him and his wife for 9 years, this bank opens an account for a mountebank posing as the wife ― without requiring any ID, or other information, from this mountebank! This rogue uses her account to hide criminal acts.

Then the bank denies liability. The bank argues that as soon as they discovered this fraud, they closed her account as soon as possible. They have always acted swiftly, and in utmost good faith. No body is perfect.

I know, this guy can complain to the [Financial Ombudsman Service](https://www.financial-ombudsman.org.uk) ― not asking about this.

##### Rather, what are my rights and liabilities against bank?

##### In legal terms, how would a lawyer analyze this fraud?

Comment: The injured parties seem to be the bank and possibly the **real** wife, not the husband.

Comment: @o.m. Yes, I know, but it's obvious that bank and TRUE wife are the injured parties. I want to know if  husband is also an injured party, and has a cause of action.

Comment: Did those criminal acts ever affect the husband, e.g. by having to explain himself to the police?

Comment: Neither husband nor wife opened this account, so they have no responsibility for it. For example if the criminal withdrew $10,000 the bank would have to refund it. But if people reasonable (but wrongly) believe that the wife is a fraudster, and this creates damages to husband and wife, that might be hard to decide.

Comment: What injury did the wife suffer?  Did she lose any money?  Did she have to spend a lot of time dealing with some administrative nightmare?  "The bank denies liability": what are they supposedly liable for?  What claim was made to prompt this denial?

Answer (score 2):

### None

The legal doctrine that a husband and wife are one legal person is long dead. The wife may have standing, the husband does not.